# How best to insert NaN values in a Python list by referring to an already sorted list

Tags: python, numpy, python-3.6

I have a sorted list containing unique values which is obtained from a master 2d list of values :

```
Sorted_List = [1,2,3,4]

Master_List =
[[1],
[1,2],
[1,4],
[3]]
```

I want to use the sorted list and convert the master list to:

```
Converted_Master_List :
[[1,NaN,NaN,NaN],
[1,2,NaN,NaN],
[1,NaN,NaN,4],
[NaN,NaN,3,NaN]]
```

How do I best do this.

Ultimately I have to write this into an CSV/excel file.

I already written code to do the sorting from master list and write the output into the CSV file, need to fill in the NaN values in between to better format the output.

Comment: What exactly is your goal? The only way you've described it is with an example. What have you tried so far?

Comment: This question is asked in continuation to the follwing question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51520673/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-read-a-specific-chunk-of-data-from-a-large-binary-fil/51521121?noredirect=1#comment90048604_51521121

Comment: That question doesn't seem to tell me much. Please edit your question to better specify your goal and include what you've tried so far.

Comment: @Quelklef : This is not a homework problem. This question is asked in continuation to the follwing question : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51520673/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-read-a-specific-chunk-of-data-from-a-large-binary-fil/51521121?noredirect=1#comment90048604_51521121)       I  want to observe patterns in the data obtained from a sensor. Those numbers are actually the peaks in the data that I'm getting from the sensor.

Comment: Sure, but that link does not help me understand exactly what your goal is. Are you trying to transform the sublists of the master lists into `range(1, 5)` where missing elements are instead `NaN`?

Comment: Also, what's the utility of `Sorted_List`? If it's a sorted list of all the data in `Master_List`, it seems redundant.

Comment: How large is your data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
Sorted_List = [1,2,3,4]

Master_List =
[[1],
[1,2],
[1,4],
[3]]

Converted_Master_List = []
for part in Master_List:
    new_part = [NaN] * len(Sorted_List)
    for i in range(len(Sorted_List)):
        if Sorted_List[i] in part:
           new_part[i] = Sorted_List[i]
    Converted_Master_List.append(new_part)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
import numpy as np

sorted_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
master_list = [[1], [1, 2], [1, 4], [3]]

# get rows and columns
rows, columns = len(master_list), max(map(max, master_list))

# create an array of rows by columns filled with np.nan
converted_master_list = np.empty((rows, columns))
converted_master_list[:] = np.nan

# set the values of the indices
for i, indices in enumerate(master_list):
    for j in indices:
        converted_master_list[i, j - 1] = j

print(converted_master_list)
```

**Output**

```
[[ 1. nan nan nan]
 [ 1.  2. nan nan]
 [ 1. nan nan  4.]
 [nan nan  3. nan]]
```

**Note:**
This approach does not uses `sorted_list` as far as I understood you don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

This will also work:

```
Master_List =[[1],[1,2],[1,4],[3]]
Sorted_List = [1,2,3,4]
i = len(Sorted_List)

for my_list in Master_List:
    if len(my_list)!= i:
        a = i - len(my_list)
        my_list.extend(a * ['nan'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a mapping `(val -> idx)` where `val` is the value from your sorted list and `idx` is the value index and use black numpy magic:

```
In [62]: sorted_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]

In [63]: master_list = [[1], [1, 2], [1, 4], [3]]

In [64]: inverted_sorted_list = pd.Series(range(len(sorted_list)), index=sorted_list)

In [65]: converted_master_list = np.full((len(master_list), len(sorted_list)), np.nan)

In [66]: for idx, lst in enumerate(master_list):
    ...:     converted_master_list[idx][inverted_sorted_list[lst]] = lst
    ...:

In [67]: converted_master_list
Out[67]:
array([[ 1., nan, nan, nan],
       [ 1.,  2., nan, nan],
       [ 1., nan, nan,  4.],
       [nan, nan,  3., nan]])
```